# MOVING PICTURES

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

[image: MOVING PICTURES]

(8 5 -> 9 6)    also as electrophenic in introduced known kuhn's of operation phrase provide respiration revolutions scientific structure support the thomas to ventilatory

(3 4 -> 4 6)    book competition corporate emotion evoke film for grueling intensive, life meant metaphor or overly requires rodential sentimental strong that to

(9 -> 8 5)  acclaimed album and arkwright breakup by creator's critically era industrial invention john kay on revolution richard second song the tyler

(6 7 -> 3 3 4)  a all and and comfortably deck each half halves having interleave into live needs one securely separate that to together

(6 8 -> 8 7)    1983 alfred as but carpenter dynamite, explosive fell illness in invention just karen mental nobel not that that's to victim

(6 4 -> 4 2 5)  a a devised dick execute how in k. novel of on philip plan policeman procedures said set the to what

(8 -> 6 5)  algorithm algorithm and are beast boy, containers different floyd's implementations in like like morph of or this two water williams'

(3 2 3 3 -> 4 8)    a about at band diagonal diagram documentary down fugitive hertzsprung-russell is large malaysian middle of prominent running still the who

(5 2 3 -> 4 2 4)    attacks characteristic disorder explosive gonna hate hate hate haters intermittent of or outbursts song sudden swift taylor the violent where

Comment: It looks like this puzzle is not original. Please could you provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: The image looks similar in style to another puzzle by the same person which, if I understand the discussion there correctly, is their own. If this is someone else's puzzle then indeed it needs attribution; if not, not.

Comment: this is my work

Comment: Not a big deal, but "electrophenic" should be "electrophrenic".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each clue

> is in fact two (definition-only, non-cryptic) clues for words or phrases with the two enumerations shown in parentheses before it, with the words sorted into alphabetical order.

And then

> each solution can itself be interpreted as cryptic-crossword-style wordplay giving an anagram; the two sets of anagram-fodder differ by just one letter.

And *then*

> putting those letters in sequence gives us the word HEMOLYSIS.

In the title,

> "Moving" can be an anagram indicator, suggesting PICTURES* to be paired with something like ICTERUS PRODUCER defined by "hemolysis", yielding ICTERUS*. I suppose that would mean that the final answer is actually the letter **P** :-).

So:

(8 5 -> 9 6) also as electrophenic in introduced known kuhn's of operation phrase provide respiration revolutions scientific structure support the thomas to ventilatory

> phrase introduced in thomas kuhn's the structure of scientific revolutions (PARADIGM SHIFT)
>  ->
>  operation to provide ventilatory support also known as electrophrenic respiration (DIAPHRAGM PACING)
>  so we have PARADIGM* and DIAPHRAGM*; difference is **H**.

(3 4 -> 4 6) book competition corporate emotion evoke film for grueling intensive, life meant metaphor or overly requires rodential sentimental strong that to

> rodential metaphor for intensive, grueling competition that corporate life requires (RAT RACE)
>  ->
>  overly sentimental book or film meant to evoke strong emotion (TEAR JERKER)
>  so we have RAT* and TEAR*; difference is **E**.

(9 -> 8 5) acclaimed album and arkwright breakup by creator's critically era industrial invention john kay on revolution richard second song the tyler

> (Nice bit of misdirection with John Kay whose band had a critically-acclaimed album called *The Second*, by the way.)
>  second song on tyler the creator's critically acclaimed breakup album (EARFQUAKE)
>  ->
>  industrial revolution era invention by richard arkwright and john kay (SPINNING FRAME)
>  so we have EARF* and FRAME*; difference is **M**.

(6 7 -> 3 3 4) a all and and comfortably deck each half halves having interleave into live needs one securely separate that to together

> separate halves and interleave each half together into a deck (RIFFLE SHUFFLE)
>  ->
>  having all that one needs to live securely and comfortably (SET FOR LIFE)
>  so we have RIFFLE* and FORLIFE*; difference is **O**.

(6 8 -> 8 7) 1983 alfred as but carpenter dynamite, explosive fell illness in invention just karen mental nobel not that that's to victim

> mental illness that karen carpenter fell victim to in 1983 (EATING DISORDER)
>  ->
>  explosive alfred nobel invention but that's not just dynamite (BLASTING GELATIN)
>  so we have EATING* and GELATIN*; difference is **L**.

(6 4 -> 4 2 5) a a devised dick execute how in k. novel of on philip plan policeman procedures said set the to what

> plan devised on how to execute a set of procedures (MASTER PLAN; shame about "plan" in the clue...)
>  ->
>  what the policeman said in a philip k. dick novel (FLOW MY TEARS)
>  so we have MASTER* and MYTEARS*; difference is **Y**.

(8 -> 6 5) algorithm algorithm and are beast boy, containers different floyd's implementations in like like morph of or this two water williams'

> williams' algorithm and floyd's algorithm are two implementations of this (HEAPSORT)
>  -->
>  morph like beast boy, or like water in different containers (CHANGE SHAPE)
>  so we have HEAP* and SHAPE*; difference is **S**.

(3 2 3 3 -> 4 8) a about at band diagonal diagram documentary down fugitive hertzsprung-russell is large malaysian middle of prominent running still the who

> documentary about a malaysian fugitive who is still at large (MAN ON THE RUN)
>  ->
>  diagonal band running down middle of the hertzsprung-russell diagram (MAIN SEQUENCE)
>  so we have MAN* and MAIN*; difference is **I**.

(5 2 3 -> 4 2 4) attacks characteristic disorder explosive gonna hate hate hate haters intermittent of or outbursts song sudden swift taylor the violent where

> taylor swift song where haters gonna hate hate hate (SHAKE IT OFF)
>  ->
>  the sudden or violent outbursts characteristic of intermittent explosive disorder (FITS OF RAGE)
>  so we have ITOFF* and FITSOF*; difference is **S**.

Comment: I'm wondering if the final answer is rot13("ubzr": n ehcghevat (ylfvf) bs "urzb")....

Comment: I think you've confused yourself on the clue you haven't got - the first word is only 6 letters, so it's probably just rot13(punatr funcr).

Comment: Oh, apparently I can't read. Duh.

Comment: @samm82 I guess that's possible, but then the title remains unexplained. I think I prefer what I've said in my answer, though I'm not terribly confident of it.

Comment: @Zandar Thanks for pointing out that I was both more and less confused than I thought I was :-). I've edited my answer so it no longer expresses puzzlement about something I shouldn't have been puzzled by.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Ah yes, somehow I missed your conclusion to the puzzle; that makes more sense to me!